# How can I make my loop start a new line every output?

Tags: python, loops, output

This is what I've got so far. The problem is at the bottom where I'm writing to a file. The data is basically a bunch of arrays I'm pulling values from and I want to write each array to a line, skip a line, and write the next array. I tried adding \n after the %s but it ends up writing everything to the file in a vertical column.

```
for i in frange(2.0, 7.5, 0.5):
    filename = str('pH')+str(i)+str('_calcpka.dat')
    readFile(array_pf, filename)      ##goes through files and takes data I need


df = []
for i in array_pf:          ##does some math and puts into new array..
    x = 1-i
    df.append(x)


titration_curves = open('titration_curves.dat', 'w')   ##writes to file
for i in df:
    titration_curves.write("%s " % i)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `df` is just an array of values, not an array of arrays. What you need to do is get your input into an array of arrays, where every inner array corresponds to one line in the file. Then you do something like:

```
for df in dfs:
    for i in df:
        titration_curves.write("%s " % i)
    titration_curves.write("\n")
```